# What are unsolved problems in chess?

Tags: theory, problems, mathematics

Are there any problems in chess that remain unsolved?

Comment: You mean strictly regarding the game itself, or in a broader sense, meaning the sporting aspect, i.e. match rules, how to train or study, etc.?

Comment: upvoted but why don't you edit further to clarify this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try finding [the perfect Babson](https://en.chessbase.com/post/the-perfect-babson): compose a problem with four main lines. They consist of a defensive promotion of a black pawn to a queen, rook, bishop or knight, which forces White to promote to the same piece type in each case.

Examples already exist, but they involve duals, which make them imperfect.

Answer (score 7):

Is there a forced win for White?

Answer (score 2):

Is it good or not for chess and the players if the World Championship match could be eventually decided by rapid, blitz, and armageddon?